# Difference between preimage resistance and second-preimage resistance

Tags: hash, cryptography

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack) says:

- *preimage resistance*: for essentially all pre-specified outputs, it is computationally infeasible to find any input which hashes to that output, i.e., it is difficult to find any preimage x given a "y" such that h(x) = y.
- *second-preimage resistance*: it is computationally infeasible to find any second input which has the same output as a specified input, i.e., given x, it is difficult to find a second preimage x' ≠ x such that h(x) = h(x′).

Yet, I don't understand it. Doesn't **h(x′)** (where **x'** is input) *generate* that **y** (the output), which is then compared to the same **h(x)**?

Say, I have a string "example". It generates the MD5 "1a79a4d60de6718e8e5b326e338ae533". Why is it different to just use the MD5 compared to doing the MD5(example)?

Comment: Are you questioning the purpose of hashing? I mean why hashes instead of plain strings. Is that what it is?

Comment: @elf maybe I'm completely misunderstanding the issue, but isn't comparing "MD5(example)" (the function with the argument) and "1a79a4d60de6718e8e5b326e338ae533" (the result) the same thing?

Comment: No they are not the same thing.. I will explain with an example below

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [cryptography](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) and not related to programming.

Comment: Read https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20997/second-pre-image-resistance-vs-collision-resistance

Comment: @xxx--- this one's solved, and that's not the same question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ideal hashing is like taking the fingerprint of a person, it is unique, it is non-reversible (you can't get the whole person back just from the fingerprint) and it can serve as a short and simple identifier for the given person.

If we bring some of the terminology you introduced into our analogy, we see that *preimage resistance* refers to the hash function's ability to be non-reversible. Imagine if you could generate the likeness of a whole person from their fingerprint, aside from being really cool, this could also be very dangerous. For the same reason, hash functions must be made so that an attacker cannot find the original message that generated the hash. In that sense, hash functions are *one-way* in that the message generates the hash and **not** the other way round.

*Second preimage resistance* refers to a given hash function's ability to be unique. Forensic fingerprinting would be a gross waste of time if any number of individuals could share the same fingerprint (lets exclude identical twins for now. **Edit:** See Det's comment below). If a given hash was used for verification against data corruption, it would quite pointless if there is a good chance corrupt data can generate the same hash.

To have both preimage resistance and second preimage resistance hash functions adopt several traits to help them. One trait very common for hash functions is where the given input has no correspondence to the output. A single bit change can produce a hash that has completely no bytes shared with the hash of the original input. For this reason, a good hash function is commonly used in message authentication.

Whilst you are right comparing the original message directly would be functionally equivalent to comparing the hashes, it is simply not feasible in the majority of cases. For example:

If party A wanted to reliably send a message to party B, party A/B would need to agree upon a scheme to detect data corruption during transfer. Note: party B does not have the original message until party A sends it.

A possible scheme of transfer could be to transfer the message twice such that party B can verify if the second message equals the first. The problem with this is that there is a chance that corruption can occur twice in the same place (as well as the significantly higher bandwidth). This can only be reduced by sending the messages even more times, incurring severe bandwidth costs.

As an alternative, party A can pass his/her long message into a hash function and generate a short hash which he/she sends to party B, followed by the original message. Party B can then take the received message and pass it into the hash function and match the hashes. If either the message or the hash got corrupted even by a single bit during transfer, the resultant hashes will not match, thanks to second preimage resistance (no two plaintext should have same hash).

Preimage Resistance in this case would be useful if the message is encrypted during transfer but the hash was taken prior encryption (whether this is appropriate is another discussion). If the hash was reversible, a eavesdropper could intercept the hash and reverse to find the original message.

All hash functions are not equal, that's why its important to consider their preimage resistance/second preimage resistance when choosing which ones to use, which ones are secure and which ones [should be deprecated and replaced](http://eprint.iacr.org/2010/643.pdf).

Comment: lol, just like a person's fingerprint... hashing is NOT unique (otherwise you would have gotten world's most advanced compression-technique). Still, for most known words, the hashes are known. Thankfully there are multiple services online that 'reverse' hashes. Known ones give instant results, unknown ones get added to the unknown matchlist.

Comment: @GitaarLAB Hashing is not unique due to limitations of the hash function as well as output size. Even if it were perfectly unique, it wouldn't be a compression technique in that its not reversible. The whole deal with second preimage resistance gives you an estimate of **how** unique a hash is.

Comment: To that, I agree. But that is different from your opening statement `Hashing is like taking the fingerprint of a person, it is unique, it is non-reversible (you can't get the whole person back just from the fingerprint) and it can serve as a short and simple identifier for the given person.` If it *were* unique, you'd have an index-number to *any* file imaginable (that would be stored on an infinite database where you could subsequently download any imaginable file from the cloud, just by it's hash).

Comment: @GitaarLAB The introduction talks about an ideal hash, whilst the main body as well as the conclusion state hash functions are not so ideal. Hash-based indexing is a thing and has been employed in various settings (look at commit indexing for git). These settings rely on the uniqueness of a given hash for the input snapshot. Most decent secure hash functions are treated as effectively unique anyway. I've added the word **ideal** in my introduction to clarify any misconceptions.

Comment: By the way, aside from the absolutely wonderful explanation, there was the joke _"lets exclude identical twins for now"_, but from [Wikipedia:Fingerprint#Latent detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerprint#Latent_detection) _"[e]ven identical twins (who share their DNA) do not have identical fingerprints"_.

Comment: @Det Hmm, didn't know that! Kinda just assumed you know... Edited answer to defer to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You understood preimage and second preimage resistance? It says the output of a hash function is unique, at least in theory.. And obtaining the original string from a hash is "computationally" in-feasible. It is possible (brute-force) though but takes up a lot of time and resources.

Now, output of a hash function and the string itself are different.. For example, consider a website with a dashboard. You provide your user_id and password at the time of signing up. If the website stores your password as such in their database, it is accessible to a hacker. He can access your account. But if a hash of your password is stored, even if he manages to hack down the server, that hash is of no use to him. Because, he cannot access your account without your password, and it is computationally in-feasible to obtain your password from the hash (preimage resistance). Comparing md5 (yourpassword) with the hash stored in the db is different. Each time you enter your password, it is hashed with the sampe hash function and compared to the existing hash. According to second-preimage resistance, if you entered an incorrect password, the hashes won't match.

Another example of hashing is in the version control or source control mechanisms. To track down changes in a file, hashing is used. They hash the entire file and keeps it. If a file is modified, its hash changes accordingly.

These are all examples explaining what you asked.

Comment: I had to just **+1** the _"Got it?"_ in the end, but [CPU Terminator](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1946537/cpu-terminator) simply has the more in-depth [explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28381589/1821548), so I went with that.

Comment: I have to admit, he took his time to explain things. I just wanted to get some reps to earn some privileges. Now I am no longer after reps. Just to share what I know. :)